# How to turn off Autocapitalize in our JSp page

Tags: html

I have a text thats getting displyed inside a Div element 
    
    Sample Text

When the text is getting displayed on the browser, first letter of all the words in the text is getting displayed in Upper case.

I tried  autocapitalize="off" to turn off auto capitalize but its not working.
Any other way to do it?

Comment: remove `text-transform: capitalize;` from your css

Comment: autocapitalize works only in inputs and textareas (yes, it auto turns off auto capitalize first word of sentence even in mobile devices where it is by default) but your div problem is weird and we cant really understand - do you insert capitalized text there or "all small letters" becomes "Now All Like This" ?

Answer (score 2):

> Inside your DIV's style try

```
text-transform: none;
```